# Cron won't run command that locks my screen

Tags: bash, cron

I want to run a cron job periodically which locks my pc.

I type any of these 3 commands in the terminal and they work:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
xdg-screensaver lock
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

When I put them in cron, nothing happens.

I have 2 other jobs that run SSH. They work while this one specifically won't.

I tried adding environments, but that wouldn't work either. This is what I tried to make crontab look like:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

* * * * * /usr/bin/xdg-screensaver lock
(newline,EOF)
```

I tried with and without `/usr/bin/` prefixes to the commands. I tried with and without environments for cron. I tried `SHELL=/bin/bash` as well.
I tried something like `nohup xdg-screensaver lock`
No results.

I tried putting it in a script, and then running the script via cron. No results.

EDIT:

I tried setting DISPLAY in crontab. When I did `echo $DISPLAY` I got `:1` in return.
I changed crontab to this:

```
DISPLAY=:1
* * * * * /usr/bin/xdg-screensaver lock
(newline,EOF)
```

My PC still won't lock. But now when I check cron's status with `service cron status` I see new things. These new lines appear:

```
   ├─25234 /usr/sbin/cron -f
   ├─25852 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
   ├─25853 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/xdg-screensaver lock
   ├─25854 /bin/sh /usr/bin/xdg-screensaver lock
   ├─25862 dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.GetNameOwner string:org.gnome.SessionManager
   ├─25863 dbus-launch --autolaunch 6cd12da16cea4d79bb7367a0f8b8bd3e --binary-syntax --close-stderr
   └─25866 dbus-launch --autolaunch 6cd12da16cea4d79bb7367a0f8b8bd3e --binary-syntax --close-stderr


Jan 23 22:38:01 riff CRON[25923]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user riff by (uid=0)
Jan 23 22:38:01 riff CRON[25924]: (riff) CMD (/usr/bin/xdg-screensaver lock)
Jan 23 22:38:01 riff dbus-daemon[25938]: [session uid=1000 pid=25936] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Jan 23 22:38:04 riff dbus-daemon[25953]: [session uid=1000 pid=25951] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Jan 23 22:38:07 riff dbus-daemon[25959]: [session uid=1000 pid=25957] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Jan 23 22:38:10 riff CRON[25923]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan 23 22:38:10 riff CRON[25923]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user riff
```

The new lines are those starting with `dbus-send`, `dbus-launch` and `dbus-daemon`

I tried setting SHELL=/bin/bash in crontab but that didn't change anything

...

After redirecting the error to a log,
Running `xdg-screensaver lock` as a cron job i get the error: 
`ERROR: Unknown command 'lock'.`

Using `gnome-screensaver -l` I get the error: 
`** Message: 23:25:04.831: Failed to get session bus: Could not connect: Connection refused`

Using `dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock` I get the error:

`Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ITbw92LLaf: Connection refused`

So I tried running the dbus-send.. command with root's crontab. Now the error is:

```
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified
Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
```

Error after running gnome-screensaver as root cron job:

```
** Message: 00:06:01.092: Failed to get session bus: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=6cd12da16cea4d79bb7367a0f8b8bd3e --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1
```

Comment: Probably needs DISPLAY set.

Comment: Your desktop environment should have a setting to lock the screen after a defined time of inactivity. That would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

`xdg-screensaver` cannot know which display handle It needs to lock. You need to set DISPLAY first.

In your current shell get your display by

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

then add your display into crontab

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 # <-- Example Display
```

use the below command for redirecting outputs to logfile

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/xdg-screensaver lock >/your/log/path.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks. It still won't work but I sort of made progress. Please check the edited question

Comment: please check my answer again.

Comment: ERROR: Unknown command 'lock'

Comment: I think the error is obvious, you may want to google it. you may try this as well `light-locker-command --lock`

Comment: I don't have that installed. I don't know what to google. I tried running a cron job $(xdg-screensaver lock) but that didn't work. I tried other commands but I got errors saying 'Connection refused'. I've edited my question. Note I am on Ubuntu 18.10, a user. So no root privileges.